# Send data from one virtual genymotion to the other without a 3rd party server

Tags: android, networking, genymotion

I have opened 2 or more genymotion virtual devices on my computer. To be precise lets assume 5 named Devices `A, B, C, D and E`. What I am trying to achieve is, I want to send data from A to the other 4 (B,C,D and E). That is, A would act as a Central Unit or a "server" in an ad hoc sort of network enviroment.

- Does genymotion provide such a service? Or, just I wrote above, I need to compromise one of the devices to do this task of sending and receiving?
- If I am not using genymotion and would do this on real devices. Assume I know the IP addresses of the 4 devices. How can I make them ready 24/7 to listen to anything that I will be sending from device A?

Comment: seems you are looking for Sockets..

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like this provided by Genymotion but it is not a problem because, you seems to be a developer and you should find a way to implement it yourself. There are tons of ways to achieve your goal, here are some of them:

- Java Sockets, it allows you to share data quite simply between your devices
- HTTP micro server (like [Nanohttpd](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd)), it allows you to create rest base protocol between your devices

Comment: I know mate. I am a lazy one though. But many thanks for putting your time and coming up with an answer.